# Count number of instances that occur in a range across a month

Tags: microsoft-excel, time

I am looking to try and work out how many times across a month a message was posted between specific times, but not a specific date. Messages can be sent at any time, and I need to calculate how many are being sent between 20:00:00 and 06:00:00. The image attached shows a range of dates and times where five of the values would fall between 20:00:00 and 06:00:00, but none of the formulas I have tried will calculate this for me. Any help would be great. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP3SJ.png

Comment: With excel the time component of a datetime is stored as a decimal. You can do CELLREF - INT(CELLREF) to leave you just the time component. Also I'm not seeing 4 instances of time > 20:00:00 or < 06:00:00, not the 7 you state in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SUMPRODUCT()` & `MOD()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(B2:B15,1)>=TIME(20,,))+(MOD(B2:B15,1)<=TIME(6,,)))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

If data are formatted as dates (numbers) and are in a range `A1:A14` you can use a formula:

```
=SUM((MOD($A$1:$A$14,1)>20/24)+(MOD($A$1:$A$14,1)<=6/24))
```

Comment: I was looking for the way to get the fractional part of a number and `Mod(...,1)` is indeed a very good approach :-)